# Dockbar Changes in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6.2

Can anyone suggest me, which file is responsible for dockbar menu changes for admin user and other user in **liferay 6.2** ?

I made changes in `\docroot\META-INF\custom_jsps\html\portlet\dockbar\view_user_account.jspf` file for the dockbar menu,
but changes is reflect only Guest user dockbar menu.

Please suggest me file where the dockbar menu comes for admin user and
other user.

Answer (score 0):

You found the correct directory - dockbar's jsps are in Liferay's `html/portlet/dockbar` folder, however there are 16 jsps in there and you either picked the wrong one or edited within some conditionals that only display for the guest user.

They're all overridden the way you're doing it already in your hook. Which file exactly contains the markup that you need to change you'll have to find for yourself. Same with the location in the file to change. Especially as you only state that you need to "make changes" - not sure if you add more options, change existing options, reorder, or just change the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

in dockbar exist public page and private page .you can manage dockbar in portal_normal.vm .
in this vm file you acces dockbar whit #dockbar()  and put condition for show or hide dockbar.